# sparkSQL - What do TungstenAggregate and TungstenExchange mean?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a very simple `count()` on a SparkSQL dataframe, here is a bit of the corresponding DAG in the web UI.

[image: Web UI DAG]

What do **TungstenAggregate** and **TungstenExchange** refer to? (Googled without result.)

Code :

```
ndata2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.textFile(filePath).map(lambda x : x.split(",")),["key","value"])
ndata2.count()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708448/what-is-tungstenexchange-mechanism-on-spark#comment61028267_36708448) by zero323,

> **TungstenExchange is a shuffle**.

However, I'm still curious to know what TungstenAggregate is.